# VS Code Promise catch handler is not called

Tags: reactjs, typescript, promise

I am writting a react + typescript application with Visual Studio Code:

[image]

react.js: 16.2.0
typescript: 2.6.2

I am using the built-in Promise library of vscode. But somehow I cannot propagate rejected promise to the caller function. Here I would like to simplify as much as I can my code (it is an already complex application).

Say I have an inner function Foo that returns a promise:

```
const Foo = (args) => {

    return new Promise( (resolve, reject) => {

         // 1. call a remote backend method (e.g ajax)
         // 2. on call success:
               resolve(success);

         // 3. on call fails:
               reject(error); // --> this error does not propagate
    }); 
}
```

Now here is the outer function Bar that calls Foo:

```
const Bar = (args) => {

    new Promise( (resolve, reject) => {

         Foo(args).then( success => {

            //...success code

         }).catch(error => {
            // ! this handle is never called
         }); 
    }) 
}
```

On the outer function Bar, the catch handler is never called!! It is like the inner promise rejection fails silently. I swear this was working until yesterday...I have spent half my Sunday trying to figure out was is going on.

I don't know anymore what to do. So I turn to Stackoverflow and the community. Is there anything I am missing about using Promise with Typescript? (before I was using the Q.js library. But I switched to the embedded promise library which comes with Vscode). Any help will really help me.

Comment: Have you tried to put a `console.log()` on the `// 3. on call fails:` block to see if the `reject` function is actually being called?

Comment: The reject function is actually called. I have set a breakpoint on this line. And it actually stops there.

Comment: One thing I have omitted (as I said, I am trying to summarize my sample code) is that the inner function Foo uses the q.js promise libray. I think this messes up with the built-in promise library of vscode

Comment: Have you tried to change the promise library?

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot change the promise library. The inner foo is a third-party libray that uses the q.js And my application uses the built-in promise lib of vscode. This was working until recently. Few days ago, I upgraded the vscode to the 1.19.3 version. I wander if this upgrade has broken my code

Comment: If you are using typescript, and the function `Foo` returns a promise, why not use `async await` in the function `Bar`.

Comment: Avoid the [`Promise` constructor antipattern](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23803743/1048572?What-is-the-promise-construction-antipattern-and-how-to-avoid-it)!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An optional second function can be passed to `.then()` to handle rejection.

```
const Bar = (args) => {

    new Promise( (resolve, reject) => {

         Foo(args).then( success => {

            //...success code

         }, error => {
            //...handle error
         }) 
    }) 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> On the outer function Bar, the catch handler is never called!! It is like the inner promise rejection fails silently. I swear this was working until yesterday...I have spent half my Sunday trying to figure out was is going on.

If the `reject` is called *after* `resolve` has been called then the promise *does not reject* as it is settled on fulfilled. Hence `catch` handlers will not be called.

Comment: I think that with the comments he meant some sort of "if" statements being used, I don't think this is the problem

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But the resolve is not called because the remote call fails. So only the reject is called